# Scheduling python scripts using while loop vs scheduling scrips using window scheduler (which one is more energy efficient?)

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

Scheduling python scripts using while loop vs scheduling scrips using window scheduler (which one is more energy efficient?)

So now that school is closed and what not, the school now wants us to sign in before a specific time. So I made a python script using selenium to log in to my school email, confirm my attendance and then closes the browser.

Which one is better? while loop or window task scheduler? I define better in terms of energy saving (hence electric bill).

I need this to run daily (except weekends) for the next 5 weeks.

Comment: If your computer is always on (which has to be the case eitherway), it would make very little difference (assuming your while loop is implemented properly with `sleep()`)

Comment: @rdas What if I don't implement sleep() function?

Comment: There is no reason for you to not use `sleep`. If you don't, your CPU usage will be higher. Look up busy-waiting

Comment: @rdas time.sleep() is what you are referring to right?

Comment: Yes............